# Two actions in one form

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form and i need to use to actions in it .
one for getting informations entered in the fields and redirect the user to another page and the other one for checking the email validation .
the email validation is for the first fields ,the other field is normal
here's my code :

```html
<form name="myform" class="login" action="getinfo.php" method="POST">
<input name="f1" type="text" placeholder="email" autofocus/>
<input name="f2" type="password" placeholder="example2"/>
```

this is the js code for checking the  first field for the email :

```
function validateForm() {
var x = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length) {
    alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
    return false;
}
```

i have no idea how to use two actions in one form
Thanks in advance, hope I have been concise and precise enough.

Comment: Recommending performing validation on the server side as JS can be disabled and might be not reliable in some cases.

Comment: don't give action attribute its value, assign it as per your condition in click of submit button and thats it

Comment: The email validation stuff is **client side** JavaScript. A form action is a URL to submit data to for processing **server side**. It doesn't make sense to use an action to run that JavaScript. Go and teach yourself about the `addEventListener` function and the `submit` event.

Comment: to run your validation, handle the form's submit event. Prevent the default postback behaviour. Run your validation. If it passes, use script to submit the form. If it fails, just display the errors. As others have said, validate it all again on the server as well because JS validation can easily be bypassed. It's nice for enhanced user experience but you cannot rely on it. Anything downloaded to the browser - HTML, script etc can be manipulated easily by a malicious user or script, so you cannot trust _anything_ that is sent back from the client.

Comment: @MaD You validate everywhere as needed not only in a single place. The backend validates it to make sure only valid emails are entered, regardless where the service method (or similar) is called from. The front end **also** validates it as it would most likely be a business requirement for users to see the email is valid on the form. You do not want a full server roundtrip to validate the email address if you can validate it on the spot. Doing it only server side is a terrible suggestion. You do both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve what you want while keeping it as close to what you had, you can do:

```js
function validateForm() {
  var x = document.forms["myform"]["f1"].value; //changed to "myform" and "f1"
  var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
  var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
  if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length) {
      alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
      return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<!--onsubmit handler added to <form> -->
<form name="myform" class="login" action="getinfo.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return validateForm()"> 
  <input name="f1" type="text" placeholder="email" autofocus/>
  <input name="f2" type="password" placeholder="example2"/>
  <input type="submit"> <!--submit button was missing -->
</form>
```

Note that the important part is the submit handler that runs when you submit the form and returns `true` if you want the form to be submitted or `false` otherwise, which you were missing.

It's also important to validate on the server side as well, otherwise any user may disable javascript and bypass the validation. 
As a side note, changing the type of the email input to email already forces validation by the browser, which is easier.

Comment: Thank you so much . can i use button tag instead of input type = submit?

Comment: Yes there is, add a value attribute with the name you want it to have (`<input .... value="someName">`). I didn't name it so it defaulted to submit.

Comment: Thank you very much you saved me