# one form button click for two actions

Tags: javascript, forms, button, click, action

I have a web page whose principle use is to capture data in a form, and then onSubmit the page should spawn another window or tab where a program processes the form data. However, once a job is launched in its own window, I don't want to block the user from filling out a new form and submitting another job.

In other words, as soon as the new page is being loaded in the new window, I want the current window and page to reload and be immediately ready for the user to enter new data into the form.

I tried code that looked like this:

```
<form action="launch.php" method="post" target="newwindow">';
<fieldset>
<button onClick="window.location.reload();">Launch</button>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

On clicking the button the code does **successfully open** the launch.php program in the new window, but it **does not reload** the current page.

I then reviewed an answer to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44823571/2708519 by https://stackoverflow.com/users/6087092/isac

Upon reading sac's answer I then rewrote my code to look like this:

```
<form action="launch.php" method="post" onsubmit="return window.location.reload()" target="newwindow">';
<fieldset>
<button>Launch</button>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

On clicking the button the code again **successfully opens** the launch.php program in the new window, but it **does not** reload the current page.

I suspect it might be best to replace the form **action** parameter or **onClick** button parameter with a **single** call to a *javascript function* call that effects both actions based on that single event. Maybe that would require an *ajax* call for one of them? If so, can someone give me an example of what that javascript function call including ajax would look like?

What is a best practice in this case? Is there a particular event that I should be binding to? Or is it immaterial?

Comment: Don't bother with opening new tabs, use AJAX instead

Comment: I don't understand this suggestion. Please consider the use case.  The user has a form they want to use to initiate a number of independent tasks.  Those tasks may take some time to complete, and the user doesn't want to have to wait for one to complete before submitting other tasks. Eventually the spawned tasks might need review (so they merit their own tab), but not until they complete.   AJAX would allow me to make a request and then put the results on the launching page - but only after that other page completes its work - this forces the user into a synchronous use case pattern!